# Remove accents from a dataframe column in R

Tags: r, diacritics

I got a data.table base.
I got a term column in this data.table

```
class(base$term)
[1] character
length(base$term)
[1] 27486
```

I'm able to remove accents from a string.
I'm able to remove accents from a vector of string.

```
iconv("Millésime",to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Millesime"
iconv(c("Millésime","boulangère"),to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Millesime" "boulangere"
```

But for some reason, it does not work when I apply the very same function on my term column

```
base$terme[2]
[1] "Millésime"
iconv(base$terme[2],to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "MillACsime"
```

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: Is it because `base$terme` is a factor? Try converting to `character` first or convert the levels maybe?

Comment: @NJBurgo According to the first output (assuming a typo), it’s of type `character`.

Comment: Careful: I get a completely different result for your vectors: ``[1] "Mill'esime"  "boulang`ere"`` The `iconv` documentation specifies that `TRANSLIT` gives different results on different systems (which is of course a bit useless).

Comment: Try `iconv(base$terme[2],from="latin1",to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")`. If it doesn't work, please give the output of `Encoding(base$terme[2])`.

Comment: Hi Nicola, the output of Encoding(base$terme[2]) is "UTF-8"

Answer (score 52):

It might be easier to use the [stringi](/questions/tagged/stringi) package. This way, you don't need to check the encoding beforehand. Furthermore [stringi](/questions/tagged/stringi) is consistent across operating systems and `iconv` is not.

```
library(stringi)
 
base <- data.table(terme = c("Millésime", 
                             "boulangère", 
                             "üéâäàåçêëèïîì"))

base[, terme := stri_trans_general(str = terme, 
                                   id = "Latin-ASCII")]
 
> base
           terme
1:     Millesime
2:    boulangere
3: ueaaaaceeeiii
```

Comment: This is the only method which worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me as well. However, if someone would like to fix the following one => `ds_itens$content <- iconv(ds_itens$content, 'utf-8', 'ascii', sub = '')` would be great. This last code is almost 100%

Answer (score 38):

Ok the way to solve the problem :

```
Encoding(base$terme[2])
[1] "UTF-8"
iconv(base$terme[2],from="UTF-8",to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Millesime"
```

Thanks to @nicola

Answer (score 14):

Here is an version of Jeldrik's solution revised for DataFrames. Note the `:=` operator is deprecated in base R.

```
library(stringi)

base <- data.frame(terme = c("Millésime", 
                             "boulangère", 
                             "üéâäàåçêëèïîì"))

base$terme = stri_trans_general(str = base$terme, id = "Latin-ASCII")
```

Answer (score 4):

Three ways to remove accents - shown and compared to each other below.
The data to play with:

```
dtCases <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccodwg/Covid19Canada/master/retired_datasets/individual_level/cases_2021_1.csv", stringsAsFactors = F )
dim(dtCases) #  751526     16
```

Bench-marking:

```
> system.time(dtCases [, city0 := health_region])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.009   0.001   0.012 
> system.time(dtCases [, city1 := base::iconv (health_region, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")]) # or ... iconv (health_region, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
   user  system elapsed 
  0.165   0.001   0.200 
> system.time(dtCases [, city2 := textclean::replace_non_ascii (health_region)])
   user  system elapsed 
  9.108   0.063   9.351 
> system.time(dtCases [, city3 := stringi::stri_trans_general (health_region,id = "Latin-ASCII")])
   user  system elapsed 
   4.34    0.00    4.46
```

Result:

```
> dtCases[city0!=city1, city0:city3] %>% unique
                           city0                         city1                         city2                         city3
                          <char>                        <char>                        <char>                        <char>
1:                      Montréal                      Montreal                      Montreal                      Montreal
2:                    Montérégie                    Monteregie                    Monteregie                    Monteregie
3:          Chaudière-Appalaches          Chaudiere-Appalaches          Chaudiere-Appalaches          Chaudiere-Appalaches
4:                    Lanaudière                    Lanaudiere                    Lanaudiere                    Lanaudiere
5:                Nord-du-Québec                Nord-du-Quebec                Nord-du-Quebec                Nord-du-Quebec
6:         Abitibi-Témiscamingue         Abitibi-Temiscamingue         Abitibi-Temiscamingue         Abitibi-Temiscamingue
7: Gaspésie-Îles-de-la-Madeleine Gaspesie-Iles-de-la-Madeleine Gaspesie-Iles-de-la-Madeleine Gaspesie-Iles-de-la-Madeleine
8:                     Côte-Nord                     Cote-Nord                     Cote-Nord                     Cote-Nord
```

Conclusion:

The `base::iconv()` is the fastest and preferred method.
Tested on French words. Not tested on other languages.

Answer (score 4):

Quick, simple, easy to modify, no dependencies:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Removes common accents from letters.
#
# @param s The string to remove diacritics from.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
accentless <- function( s ) {
  chartr(
    "áéóūáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚýÝàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãõÃÕñÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜÿçÇ",
    "aeouaeiouAEIOUyYaeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOUaoAOnNaeiouAEIOUycC",
    s );
}
```

Comment: The semicolon is unnecessary

Comment: StackOverflow is a wiki.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply this function

```
    rm_accent <- function(str,pattern="all") {
   if(!is.character(str))
    str <- as.character(str)

  pattern <- unique(pattern)

  if(any(pattern=="Ç"))
    pattern[pattern=="Ç"] <- "ç"

  symbols <- c(
    acute = "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚýÝ",
    grave = "àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ",
    circunflex = "âêîôûÂÊÎÔÛ",
    tilde = "ãõÃÕñÑ",
    umlaut = "äëïöüÄËÏÖÜÿ",
    cedil = "çÇ"
  )

  nudeSymbols <- c(
    acute = "aeiouAEIOUyY",
    grave = "aeiouAEIOU",
    circunflex = "aeiouAEIOU",
    tilde = "aoAOnN",
    umlaut = "aeiouAEIOUy",
    cedil = "cC"
  )

  accentTypes <- c("´","`","^","~","¨","ç")

  if(any(c("all","al","a","todos","t","to","tod","todo")%in%pattern)) # opcao retirar todos
    return(chartr(paste(symbols, collapse=""), paste(nudeSymbols, collapse=""), str))

  for(i in which(accentTypes%in%pattern))
    str <- chartr(symbols[i],nudeSymbols[i], str) 

  return(str)
}
```

Comment: Unlike `iconv` this isn't vectorized and doesn't cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Based on jf2017 code, here is a tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)    
base %>%
   # latin-ASCII-free "term" column (careful: this overwrites the original "term" column!)
   mutate(term = stringi::stri_trans_general(str = term, id = "Latin-ASCII")
```

To apply to all columns in your data frame, use

```
base %>%
mutate(across(.cols = everything(),
              .fns = ~ stringi::stri_trans_general(., id = "Latin-ASCII")))
```

Run `stringi::stri_trans_list()` to see all available parameters that id can take

Answer (score 1):

The `iconv` option didn't work in my computer, but I solved this issue using the `replace_non_ascii` function from the `textclean` package.