# Gsub to gsubfn, how does it transfer?

Tags: r, gsub, gsubfn

I am cleaning my dataset and removing all accents on letters and such. In order to do this I use gsub (see code below). It works perfectly fine but I am sure there is a more convenient way to do it. I've heard about gsubfn but I have not been able to figure out how it works. Any tips on that or on any other way to make this code more efficient?

```
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub(' ', "", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("'", "", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("/", "", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("Ë", "E", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("É", "E", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("È", "E", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("Ç", "C", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("À", "A", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("Ù", "U", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("Œ", "OE", Ech_final$lastname.y)
Ech_final$lastname.y <- gsub("Ï", "I", Ech_final$lastname.y)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks quite readable to me. Are you experiencing performance issues?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39148759/680068, try `iconv("ÉÈÇÀÙŒÏ", from = "latin1", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")`

Comment: None of the answers to the purported duplicate question address the Subject line of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several alternatives. The first uses `gsubfn` as requested by the Subject line of the question.  The next two use `iconv` or `chartr` for the substitutions for which the replacement is one character and `gsub` for the remaining replacements.  The last two use `gsub` for all substitutions using `Reduce` or a loop.

**1) gsubfn** `gsubfn` is used like this where the first argument says to match each character, the second is a translation list and the third is the input.

```
library(gsubfn)

x <- " '/ËÉÈÇÀÙŒÏ"   # input

L <- list(" " = "", "'" = "", "/" = "", Ë = "E", É = "E", È = "E", 
    Ç = "C", À = "A", Ù = "U", Œ = "OE", Ï = "I")

gsubfn(".", L,  x)
## [1] "EEECAUOEI"
```

**2) gsub/iconv** Another approach is a mix of `gsub` for those cases where the replacement is not one character and `iconv`.  The input `x` is defined above.

```
Encoding(x)  # note the encoding
## [1] "latin1"

x |>
  gsub(pattern = "Œ", replacement = "OE") |>
  gsub(pattern = "[ '/]", replacement = "") |>
  iconv("latin1", "ascii//translit")
## [1] "EEECAUOEI"
```

**3) gsub/chartr** A third alternative is the same as (2) except we use `chartr` in place of `iconv`.  The input `x` is defined above.

```
x |>
  gsub(pattern = "Œ", replacement = "OE") |>
  gsub(pattern = "[ '/]", replacement = "") |>
  chartr(old = "ËÉÈÇÀÙÏ", new = "EEECAUI")
## [1] "EEECAUOEI"
```

**4) gsub/Reduce** This alternative performs the `gsub` calls shown in the question but does it in a more compact form using `Reduce`.  The list `L` and the input `x` are from (1).

```
Reduce(function(s, nm) gsub(nm, L[[nm]], s), names(L), x)
## [1] "EEECAUOEI"
```

**5) gsub/for** One could use a simple `for` loop to run the `gsub` calls in the question.  The list `L` and the input `x` are from (1).

```
xx <- x
for(nm in names(L)) xx <- gsub(nm, L[[nm]], xx)
xx
## [1] "EEECAUOEI"
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer!

For the gsubfn option, what does the "." mean?

Comment: It is a regular expression which matches each character (as mentioned in answer).