# Accent insensitive regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to use `filter(grepl())` to match some words in my column. Let's suppose I want to extract the word "Guartelá". In my column, i have variations such as "guartela" "guartelá" and "Guartela". To match upper/lowercase words I'm using `(?i)`. However, I haven't found a good way to match accent/no-accent (i.e., "guartelá" and "guartela").

I know that I can simply substitute `á` by `a`, but is there a way to assign the accent-insensitive in the code? It can be base R/tidyverse/any, I don't mind.

Here's how my curent code line is:

```
cobras <- final %>% filter(grepl("(?i)guartelá", NAME) 
                           | grepl("(?i)guartelá", locality))
```

Cheers

Comment: You can remove all accented characters before you try to the match. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56595128/2372064. But I don't think regular expressions themselves have classes identifying synonymous accented characters. You'd have to define the classes yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass options in `OR` statements using `[` to capture different combinations

```
> string <- c("Guartelá", "Guartela", "guartela", "guartelá", "any")
> grepl("[Gg]uartel[aá]", string)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Damn, I didn't know I could use [] for this...pretty amazing

Answer (score 5):

you can use stri_trans_general fron stringi to remove all accents:

```
unaccent_chars= stringi::stri_trans_general(c("guartelá","with_é","with_â","with_ô")  ,"Latin-ASCII")
unaccent_chars
# [1] "guartela" "with_e"   "with_a"   "with_o" 
# grepl(paste(unaccent_chars,collapse = "|"), string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `str_detect()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(name = c("guartela","guartelá", "Guartela", "Other")) |> 
  filter(str_detect(name, "guartela|guartelá|Guartela"))
```