# R {quanteda}: remove accents in a dictionary

Tags: r, dictionary, encoding, punctuation

I want to remove accents and punctuation from a dictionary. For example, I want to transform  "à l'épreuve" into "a l epreuve". The dictionary is this one: https://www.poltext.org/fr/donnees-et-analyses/lexicoder (.cat).
There are explanations for dataframes ([Remove accents from a dataframe column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148759/remove-accents-from-a-dataframe-column-in-r)), but I could not find a way of removing for dictionaries.

My code so far:

```
dict_lg <- dictionary(file = "frlsd/frlsd.cat", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(quanteda)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)

dict_lg_ascii <- 
  dict_lg |> 
  rapply(f = \(term) term |>
              ## compose from string utilities as desired       
              stri_trans_general(id = 'Latin-ASCII') |>
              str_replace_all(pattern = '[[:punct:]]', replacement = ' '),
         how = 'replace'
         )
```

output:

```
## > dict_lg_ascii
Dictionary object with 2 primary key entries and 2 nested levels.
- [NEGATIVE]:
  - a cornes, a court de personnel , a l etroit, a peine , abais , 
## truncated
```

from the docs:

> Dictionaries can be subsetted using [ and [[, operating the same as the
> equivalent list operators.

Thus `rapply` (recursively applying a function over nested lists) works. In this case, we apply `stri_trans_general` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148759/remove-accents-from-a-dataframe-column-in-r).

Comment: You can tailor your string processing with numerous utilities from {stringi} and {stringr}. I edited the question to include @shghm 's removal of the `[:punct:]` character class, but try yourself for an optimal solution (I have just basic experience with string manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

This post might help: [Remove all special characters from a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294284/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

The `stringr`-package together with regular expressions are probably a good way to deal with it.

Comment: I tried ```str_replace_all(dict_lg, "[[:punct:]]", " ")``` but I received the following error ```string` must be a vector, not a <dictionary2> object.```